# Факториал какого максимального числа можно сохранить?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, битовые-операции, информатика

При хранении факториала некоторого натурального числа в k > 37 двоичных разрядах три старших бита были равны нулю, но факториал уже следующего числа сохранить в тех же k разрядах было невозможно. Позже было решено хранить в этих разрядах только значащие двоичные цифры факториала – без хвостовых нулей. Факториал какого максимального числа можно сохранить теперь. В случае, если правильных ответов несколько, **то запишите ответ для минимально возможного значения k.**

Comment: И зачем надо было удалять предыдущий вопрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо обязательно математически? Или можно программно?

Программно (ну, или ручным подсчетом :)) убеждаемся, что минимальным таким числом, которое должно быть не меньше 2^38, является 14!, которое помещается в 37 бит, а следующему нужно уже 41 бит. Ergo, k = 40.

Теперь нужно найти это число. Опять же, можно мучиться и считать, сколько двоек в том или ином факториале в качестве сомножителей. Впрочем, это несложно -

```
floor(n/2) + floor(n/4) + floor(n/8) + ...
```

А можно набросать программку, и убедиться, что последним, кто вот так влезет в 40 бит - будет 18!.

Все, k = 40, максимальный сохраняемый таким образом факториал - 18!.

Comment: как всегда на высоте))помогите еще с задачей про графы у меня в профиле